# How to remove duplicate dict from list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list of dicts where sometime there are duplicate dict. For ex:

```
objList = 
[{
    'Name': 'plate',
    'StartTime': '2022-05-17T10:26:05.738101',

}, {
    'Name': 'bezel',
    'StartTime': '2022-05-17T10:26:09.922667',

}, {
    'Name': 'chrome',
    'StartTime': '2022-05-17T10:26:23.283304',

}, {
    'Name': 'plate placement',
    'StartTime': '2022-05-17T10:26:25.570845',

}, {
    'Name': 'plate placement',
    'StartTime': '2022-05-17T10:26:39.3390',
}]
```

In above data, `plate placement` is duplicated. Similarly, any dict can be duplicated but I have delete any of the duplicate data and just keep one. For this, first I thought of checking if in the list we have duplicate dicts or not:

```
obj_names = []
for obj in objList:
    obj_names.append(obj['Name'])
```

Now `obj_names` contains `['plate', 'bezel', 'chrome', 'plate placement', 'plate placement']`. So this way we know that which dict is duplicated. We now have to delete any one of its occurrences. How can we delete that occurrence from the list?

Comment: @MechanicPig Can you please explain this in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mugiseyebrows said, we use the `'Name'` of each dictionary (this statement is not very rigorous.) as the key and the dictionary itself as the value to create a new dictionary so that you can ensure that a dictionary with the same `'Name'` appears once, and then use its `values` to create a new list:

```
>>> new_dict = {dct['Name']: dct for dct in objList}
>>> new_list = list(new_dict.values())
>>> print('},\n'.join(str(new_list).split('},')))
[{'Name': 'plate', 'StartTime': '2022-05-17T10:26:05.738101'},
 {'Name': 'bezel', 'StartTime': '2022-05-17T10:26:09.922667'},
 {'Name': 'chrome', 'StartTime': '2022-05-17T10:26:23.283304'},
 {'Name': 'plate placement', 'StartTime': '2022-05-17T10:26:39.3390'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of list of dictionaries you can use dictionary of dictionaries using name as a key. This way if you insert new object with same name it will replace previous object.

If you need to preserve order you can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).